# Mocking in Tests with @MockBean or @Autowired

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, junit4

I have this Junit test, where I have an object that I want to mock the `BackendHotelService` object; I used `@MockBean` and `@Autowired`, but in both I got a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when running the test

```
@Component
public class FindHotelDataRequestTransformer extends HotelDataRequestTransformer {


    public FindHotelDataRequestTransformer(BackendHotelService backendHotelService) {
        super (backendHotelService);
    }
..
}
```

and the test:

```
public class FindHotelDataRequestTransformerTest {

    @MockBean
    //@Autowired
    private BackendHotelService backendHotelService;

    private FindHotelDataRequestTransformer transformer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        transformer = new FindHotelDataRequestTransformer( backendHotelService);
    }
```

the backendHotelService is never used

Comment: you do not have a SpringRunner defined for your tests so actually the context is not set up so `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` will not even be evaluated. Try adding `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` above your test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new FindHotelDataRequestTransformer, do you access any fields of backendHotelService?

if so you will need to mock the response.

Try below

`Mockito.when(backendHotelService.name()).thenReturn("test);`